# How to click and edit text fields in apps?

Tags: automation, autohotkey, ui-automation

I need in Davinci Resolve to select in the inspector window the zoom text field using the Acc library:

[image]

I used Accessible Info Viewer to find identifying properties but hit a wall trying to selecting the text field and double clicking it to replace its value.

[image]

Code:

```
#+j:: 
WinGet, hWnd, ID, A
vAcc := Acc_Get("Object", "4.2.2.1.1.2.4.1.3.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.2.1", 0, "ahk_id" hWnd)
%vAcc%.accDoDefaultAction(0)
return
```

How to enter a new value in the zoom box? Manually, you double click it and enter a value. I have a script that does this with `SendInput` but want to without needing panels to be in specific positions prior to activating the hotkey.

Comment: Please lose all the irrelevant chat and unnecessary noise in future posts. This isn't a chatroom or forum. It's a technical question and answer site, so please be clear and concise when explaining the problem, and keep the verbiage to a minimum. You may want to review the [help] pages, especially [ask], to improve your experiences here.

Comment: Sorry man, I'm super new here

Comment: Yes, I can see that. :-) That's why I edited out the irrelevant content from your post and offered some advice for your future experiences here.

Comment: If you use Window Spy (should have been installed with your Autohotkey installation) you can get the ID of the control. The use the command "ControlSend" to send text to it. E.g. if the Zoom control is named zoomX and the window is named "Davinci Resolve",  and you want a zoom of 2.00 the try:
    #+j:: 
    ControlSend , zoomX, 2, Davinci Resolve

Answer (score 0):

Use [UIAutomation](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=104999) instead. It is the successor to the Acc/MSAA framework.

Here is the example1 code

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance force
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

;#include <UIA_Interface> ; Uncomment if you have moved UIA_Interface.ahk to your main Lib folder
#include ..\Lib\UIA_Interface.ahk

Run, notepad.exe
UIA := UIA_Interface() ; Initialize UIA interface
WinWaitActive, ahk_exe notepad.exe
npEl := UIA.ElementFromHandle("ahk_exe notepad.exe") ; Get the element for the Notepad window
documentEl := npEl.FindFirstByType("Document") ; Find the first Document control (in Notepad there is only one). This assumes the user is running a relatively recent Windows and UIA interface version 2+ is available. In UIA interface v1 this control was Edit, so an alternative option instead of "Document" would be "UIA.__Version > 1 ? "Document" : "Edit""
documentEl.Highlight() ; Highlight the found element
documentEl.Value := "Lorem ipsum" ; Set the value for the document control. 
; Equivalent ways of setting the value:
; documentEl.CurrentValue := "Lorem ipsum"
; documentEl.SetValue("Lorem ipsum")
ExitApp
```

Use some find methods (FindFirstByName, FindFirstByType, ...) to get the element you want to click, and then call element.Click().

[UIAutomation
Github wiki](https://github.com/Descolada/UIAutomation/wiki)